# How to put several elements into one?

Tags: r, list

I have a vector called `corp`:

```
corp <- c("Gruppo Multi SA,Muralto", "Impresa Barella", "Commissione intercomunale dei trasporti")

corp
Gruppo Multi SA, Muralto
Impresa Barella
Commissione intercomunale dei trasporti
```

Now I'd like to put all those elements into one element that `myoutput`looks like this:

```
myoutput
Gruppo Multi SA, Muralto;Impresa Barella;Commissione intercomunale dei trasporti
```

My difficulty lies in the fact that the length of `corp` differs. I tried something like this, but obviously it didn't work out because the loop overwrites `myoutput`every time:

```
for (i in 1:length(corp){
myoutput <- paste0(corp[i], sep=";")
}
```

Is there another way to do this, maybe a more elegant way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
corp <- c("Gruppo Multi SA,Muralto", "Impresa Barella", "Commissione intercomunale dei     trasporti")
paste(corp,collapse=";")
```